# Using URL to populate Text Box ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

I have made a ASP.net (aspx) website but need help to populate the textbox using the URL so I can send the URL to someone else and when they click/open the link the textbox is already filled out.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMessages" runat="server" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>

        string strMessage = txtMessages.Text;
```

Something like this -

```
http://localhost/TextInput.aspx?txtMessages=HelloWorld
```

So when the link is pressed the txtMessages textbox already has HelloWorld inserted into it.

I think the URL format would be something like that but it doesn't work.

Comment: have a look on http://www.dotnetperls.com/querystring will slove your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want to read the URL and then populate the Text box with whatever is in the URL?

If so try:

```
String Txtmessage = Request.QueryString["txtMessages"];
```

Then use Txtmessage to populate your textbox

Comment: Thanks for all the answers but your 1 line worked fine. however it is square brackets not normal ones.

Comment: Oh my bad, I've been working with vb.net a lot recently - That explains the normal brackets.. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Create a hyperlink on the page with your textbox:

```
HyperLink hl = new HyperLink();
hl.NavigateUrl = "yoursite.aspx?txtMessages=" + yourtextbox.Text;
```

on the page yoursite.aspx get the value on `Page_Load`:

```
 string txtMessage = Page.Request.QueryString.ToString();
 txtMessage = txtMessage.Replace("txtMessages=", "");
```

You can combine more `QueryString` like:

```
 "yoursite.aspx?action=change&txtMessages=" + yourtextbox.Text;
```

and grab it like:

```
string action = Page.Request.QueryString["action"].ToString();
string txtMessage = Page.Request.QueryString["txtMessages"].ToString();
```